# how to optimize list view having more than one views to inflate

Tags: android, performance, android-listview, out-of-memory, listadapter

I am trying to use a custom list view having 6 different types of convert views to inflate like

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
switch(case)
{
case 1:
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item1, null);
break;
case 2:
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item2, null);
break;
case 3:
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item3, null);
break;
case 4:
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item4, null);
break;
case 5:
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item5, null);
break;
default: 
break;
}
```

I having totally different views for all the above views and has many images loaded 
Now the problem is that i want to optimize this because list is very leggy and also cause out of memory exception most of time .
Please guide me , Thanks in advance

Comment: What device are you using to get the `OutOfMemoryError` exception? I do not see anything wrong here. It is most likely the processing of the many images that is causing the lag and exception.

Comment: Can you please post your Adapter code? Or if you can't, can you please explain how have you specified that this adapter should instantiate several types of views? At the moment there is nothing wrong with this code